# Multiple Developer account certificates in keychain Access in mac

Tags: ios, certificate, keychain

I am new to handling certificates in Keychain, i don't have much knowledge about it.

We are having 2 individual developer accounts in Apple. for example account X and Account Y.

With Account X we created many apps and its certificates are there in keychain. Now we created account Y to develop 1 app.

so i have created CSR,Development certificates for that app and downloaded, so when i double click on it, it will be added to KEYCHAIN ACCESS.

so my question is as ACCOUNT Y is new will its certificates make any problem to my existing certificates of ACCOUNT X.

do i need to login in KEYCHAIN ACCESS with ACCOUNT Y, if yes how can i login ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there will be no any effect to your Account X.
You can develop and upload your app using Account X and Account Y

Keychain is a single platefrom which will contain multiple developer account Certificate.

No need to login again with another account to you keychain.

Comment: I have created and downloaded CSR, so now if i double click it will be added to keychain, will it become any default CSR for other certificates also ?

Comment: there is no any concept of Default CSR.

Comment: are you sure that if i add certificates of Account Y to keychain, it will not cause any problems to my certificates of Account X ?

Comment: Dont worry Abdul :) go ahead and keep Xcoding

Comment: I have uploaded multiple clients app to app store with different apple developer account. I am sure about it.

Comment: ok i will try, if everything goes smooth, i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple Apple developer accounts on the same Mac machine without any problems. All you need is the correct installation of Certificates in Keychain for your 2nd account (Account Y) & the corresponding provisioning profiles.

With Xcode8 you can manage the certificates pretty easily (automatically) by the Xcode itself. Create the certificate requests from same Mac and use it in Account Y developer account to create its corresponding certificate to download and related provisioning profile. It would work with no problems at all.

Comment: how to do that ? can you explain step wise please ?

Comment: 1. create certificate request. 2. Login to apple developer portal and create certificate using the .csr file created in step1. 3. Download the certificate and double click to install it in keychain. 4. Create provisioning profile from apple developer portal and select the certificate created in step 2. 5. Download provisioning profile and double click to install provisioning profile with Xcode. 6. Select the provisioning profile in build settings.

Comment: yeah i did till downloading CSR and Development provisioning profile, only am afraid to double click and adding it to keychain, Am afraid thinking may be it will cause problem to my existing certificates of Account X.